# access variables via global delegate in cocoa

Tags: cocoa

I used the codes below to access the variable 'myInt' in the iPhone( coacoa touch) project

```
appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
UIApplication *app=[UIApplication sharedApplication];
appDelegate.myInt=1;
```

It works.

But when I try to migrate the project to Cocoa, I found there is no way to do the same functions as above. How can I use delegate concept to access the global variables (not use 'extern NSInteger myInt')

the codes below does not work

```
appDelegate =(AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSApplication *app=[NSApplication sharedApplication];
appDelegate.myInt=1;
```

appDelegate.myInt returns nothing

Welcome any comment

Comment: What do you mean by 'when I try to migrate the project to Cocoa'? Cocoa is just the framework, which is also used by your first code snippet.

Comment: The first part codes are for iPhone ( cocoa touch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that in the second snippet, you don't have `myInt` declared as a [property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) of your delegate class (or have it declared incorrectly), which means you can't use the dot syntax `obj.prop` to access it. There are two easy changes you can make.

Either access `myInt` using regular old method call syntax:

```
[appDelegate myInt];
```

or change your app delegate to declare that variable as a property:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSInteger myInt;
}
@property (assign) NSInteger myInt;
@end
```

---

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate
@synthesize myInt;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could make sure that `appDelegate` is indeed an instance of `AppDelegate`.

```
NSLog(@"[appDelegate isKindOfClass:[AppDelegate class]] returns %@", [appDelegate isKindOfClass:[AppDelegate class]] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

Although I find it unlikely you could also make sure that `appDelegate` isn't nil.